# When do we need to actually synchronization? My threads are naturally synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading

This is my sample class: I have a shared object `CustomerAccount` shared between two threads `Man` and `Woman`. Whenever I run the program, the results are consistent. Why is it so?

Main Class :

```
package testjava;

public class PlaywithThreads {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CustomerAccount ca=new CustomerAccount(0);
        ThreadRunner1 tr1=new ThreadRunner1(ca,"Man");
        ThreadRunner1 tr2=new ThreadRunner1(ca,"Woman");

        tr1.start();
        tr2.start();
        tr1.join();
        tr2.join();
        System.out.println("Final amount left after month"+ca.acctBalance);
    }
}
```

Thread class:

```
package testjava;

public class ThreadRunner1 extends Thread{
    private CustomerAccount ca;

    ThreadRunner1 (CustomerAccount ca,String name)
       {

          super (name); 

          this.ca = ca; 
          System.out.println("after this it will create new object");
       }

@Override
public void run() {
    Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
    String name = current.getName();
    System.out.println("Name is"+name);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (name.equals("Man")){
        //CustomerAccount caMan = new CustomerAccount();
        /*ca.creditSalary(80000);
        System.out.println(name+""+ca.acctBalance);
        ca.debitFood(8000);

        ca.debitLoans(40000);
        System.out.println(name+""+ca.acctBalance);
        ca.creditBonus(3);

        ca.debitTransport(2000);*/
        ca.acctBalance=ca.acctBalance+80000;
        ca.acctBalance=ca.acctBalance-8000;
        ca.acctBalance=ca.acctBalance-40000;
        ca.acctBalance=ca.acctBalance+3;
        ca.acctBalance=ca.acctBalance-2000;
        System.out.println(name+"----------finally------------"+ca.acctBalance);
    }

    if (name.equals("Woman")){

        //CustomerAccount caWoMan = new CustomerAccount();
        /*ca.creditSalary(50000);
        System.out.println(name+""+ca.acctBalance);
        ca.creditBonus(4);

        ca.debitClothes(20000);


        ca.debitLoans(9000);*/
        ca.acctBalance=ca.acctBalance+50000;
        ca.acctBalance=ca.acctBalance+4;
        ca.acctBalance=ca.acctBalance-20000;
        ca.acctBalance=ca.acctBalance-9000;
        System.out.println(name+"---------Finally-------"+ca.acctBalance);
    }

}
}
```

Shared Object:

```
package testjava;

public class CustomerAccount {

    int acctBalance;


   // private static int counter;

    public CustomerAccount(int initialBalance) {
        System.out.println("entered");

        this.acctBalance=initialBalance;
        //System.out.println("objects created******************"+counter);
    }
    public void debitFood(int amt){
        System.out.println("debiting food items::for"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        acctBalance = acctBalance-amt;
        System.out.println("New acct Balance after food debits::"+acctBalance);
    }
    public void debitClothes(int amt){
        System.out.println("debiting clothescost::"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        acctBalance = acctBalance-amt;
        System.out.println("New acct Balance after clotehs debits::"+acctBalance);
    }
    public void debitTransport(int amt){
        System.out.println("debiting transport::"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        acctBalance = acctBalance-amt;
        System.out.println("New acct Balance after transport debit::"+acctBalance);
    }
    public void debitLoans(int amt){
        System.out.println("debiting loans::"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        acctBalance =acctBalance-amt;
        System.out.println("New acct Balance after Loans debit::"+acctBalance);
    }
    public void creditSalary(int salary){
        System.out.println("crediting salary for ::"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        acctBalance =acctBalance+salary;
        System.out.println("New acct Balance after salary credit::"+acctBalance);
    }
    public void creditBonus(int salary){
        System.out.println("crediting bonus for ::"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        acctBalance =acctBalance+salary;
        System.out.println("New acct Balance after salary credit::"+acctBalance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes ,because its giving the result correctly after both the threads do their work.51007 that would be the same result i get when i add or subtract the amounts from a common balance .

Comment: What do you mean by "My threads are naturally synchronized"? From what I see from our code they are not.

Comment: The code is too simple, if you want to see effect of synchronization try to add a random wait in `run` method, something like: 
`Thread.sleep(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000))`

Comment: I'm sorry but that's a horrible piece of code you have here by a lot of means. I would suggest posting it to the stackoverflow's CodeReview for your improvement.

Comment: bashnesnos- that hurt.

Answer (score 0):

As the `CustomerAccount` object is shared you should handle synchronisation there. This cannot be done with direct member access (which is a bad idea from encapsulation point anyway). I would recommend to have a look into `AtomicInteger` as a better type for `acctBalance` which is thread safe out of the box but you also can make all methods of `CustomerAccount` synchronised.

It may look like the threads are synchronized as you have a lot of access to synchronising `System.out.println()`! If you would remove that printf debugging and create higher load you would see different behaviour.

Comment: I have removed the println statements , i understand now that my operations will carry on serially no matter what the sleep time and give same result.i am thinking of creating a more complex operations to see it fail in .Any suggestions?